# C# MVC new user facebook registration not working for unknown Facebook accounts

Tags: c#, facebook, authentication

I have created an MVC 5 application that should allow any Facebook user to signin/register using their Facebook accounts.

But it only seems to work with facebook accounts that are directly related to the facebook app via the facebook roles tab (in other words, the facebook app administrator).

If you try to register with any other Facebook account we receive the following error message from Facebook,

> App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login.

I got the Oauth client registration on the AuthConfig.cs as:

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(
            appId: "[my app id]",
            appSecret: "[my app secret]");
```

And im using the Controller Actions designed for this matter:

```
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        return new ExternalLoginResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
    }
```

And the related Callback:

```
public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {

        AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));

         if (!result.IsSuccessful)
                    {  
                        //[CODE TO EXECUTE IF ITS AUTHENTICATED]   
                    }
   }
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the application in the [Facebook Developer's page](https://developers.facebook.com/)?

You need to do this in order to have facebook recognize the app id you're passing in the request.

Try following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on)